# JPA JoinTable keeps on adding distinct

Tags: java, spring, jpa, ebean

I've got the following tables:
**table0
tableA
tableB**

> tableA has property

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name='table0', joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name='t_id', referencedColumnName='id'), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(...) 
bes // list of objects from tableB
```

The problem is that when I am trying to fetch list of objects with criteria eg `bes.name = 'abc'` it keeps on sending query with distinct on all fields of tableA

`select distinct t0.id, t0.name, /* and so on */`

How can I remove this 'distinct' or change it to 'distinct on(t0.id)' ?

Comment: Show us your JPA query.

Comment: Can you please post the whole mapping?

Comment: What is the problem in having DISTINCT on all columns? It is a standard way of fetching unique records, It will return the same result as DISTINCT ON (id). DISTINCT ON () is nonstandard clause, it works only in PostgreSQL as far as I know.